# ESLint: to fix this, wrap the initialization of constant in its own useMemo()

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I get this eslint warning:

> ESLint: The 'variables' object makes the dependencies of useEffect
> Hook (at line 36) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the
> initialization of 'variables' in its own useMemo()
> Hook.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

for the following piece of code:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  // ...
  const variables = {
    orgID: org.id,
    projectIDs: projects.map(p => p.id)
  };
  const { data, error, loading } = myGraphqlQuery({ variables });

  useEffect(
    () => myOtherFunction(client, channel, query, variables),
    [variables, channel, client],
  );
  // ...
}
```

I don't get it, what should I do here? What's the point of using useMemo for the const?

Comment: At each render you are creating a new Object `variables`. So your useEffect will be triggered at every render

Comment: that's so weird that you have to do that for the const variable

Comment: you're declaring a new const :) An javascript cannot compare object key.values but only references, `{} === {} // false` so you each time have a new object in your dependenvy array, so it triggers the useEffect at each render :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the initialization of your variable with a useMemo.

```
const variables = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    orgID: org.id,
    projectIDs: projects.map(p => p.id)
  };
, [
// add the necessary dependencies here
]);
```

Comment: Not sure what I expected from javascript but I'm surprised you have to do such optimization for const variables. Anyway, thank you!