# Javascript filter object by condition on only one of its keys

Tags: javascript

I have an object with the following structure:

```
data = 
{
  columns: array of objects,
  rows: [
    {
      id: 1,
      process: "A",
      status: "ok"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      process: "A",
      status: "ko"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      process: "B",
      status: "ok"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I then want to create another object that has the same `column` values, but in the `rows` field I want to put only the objects that have `process === "A"`.

I've come up with this so far, that I think it's fine:

```
const filteredData = {
    "columns": data.columns,
    "rows": selectedProcess !== '' ? data.rows.filter(r => r.process === selectedProcess) : []
  }
```

My question is if there is another way to make this in a more clever way.

Comment: That warning seems to be specific to React.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70988956/eslint-to-fix-this-wrap-the-initialization-of-constant-in-its-own-usememo

Comment: Yeah, I noted the linked answer and I'm following it to avoid the React warning, thank you. Maybe I can leave out this from the question. The point is if there is a general way to filter an object in the way I want

Comment: Your filtering method looks fine to me.

Comment: I don't think you need the ternary. If `selectedProcess` is empty, it won't match anything, so you'll get an empty result automatically.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get JavaScript object from array of objects by value of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property)

Comment: Thanks @AlveMonke, your link answers my question related to the filtering of `rows` keyword. My goal was also to keep the 'columns` keyword as in the original object and filter the `rows` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the solution Below:

```js
const filteredData = {
    "columns": data.columns,
    "rows": data.rows.filter(item=>item.process==='A')
  }
```